# session with multilingual website - codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codexworld.com/multi-language-implementation-in-codeigniter/) but when selecting another language in the dropdown, the text doesn't switch to another language. The redirect works however.

I am using database session and the `site_lang` value in the database is changed correctly.
I did a `print_r($return_lang)` in my view, `return_lang` being `$data['return_lang'] = $this->session->all_userdata();` and the result is:

> Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1458691563 )

It looks like the `site_lang` is never present there. Only in the database. I can't figure out what's wrong.

I used the Hooks method of the tutorial, the 3 language files are created under the language folder and I entered the following in my htaccess (from another tutorial) :

> RewriteEngine On RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
>
> RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php)

This is my homeController:

```
<?php
class homeController extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $data['main_content'] = 'home';
        $data['return_lang'] = $this->session->all_userdata();
        $this->load->view('templates/default',$data); 
    }
    function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $ci->load->helper('language');
        $siteLang = $ci->session->userdata('site_lang');
        if ($siteLang) {
            $ci->lang->load('message',$siteLang);
        } else {
            $ci->lang->load('message','english');
        }
    }
}
```

The other files are exactly the same as described in the tutorial.

There is one line I don't understand in `LanguageSwitcher.php` :

> function switchLang($language = "") {

Why do we set language to `""` ?
I tried to remove `= ""` and it didn't help anyway...

**UPDATE 1:**

I found one of the problem:

`$config['base_url']` was set to `' '` and I get the expected behavior **only** when using 127.0.0.1 instead of `localhost` in the URL.

I then changed to:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/mySite/';
```

but it only works when using localhost in the URL.

Using `$config['base_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1/mySite/';` makes it work fine **only** when using the ip address in the URL bar.

I would like to get it to work for anything (localhost and ip address).
When I say it doesn't work as expected, the `[site_lang]` session is not populated with english/french/german.

Comment: thanks I understand now. Just found out something... I updated my question.

Comment: why do you want to make a difference between localhost or 127.0.0.1, both are local, only your machine can access it anyway?

Comment: That is because your session is not saved if your `$config['base_url']` does not match the url you use to access the site. The cookie used for saving the session information does not match the domain you use, so CodeIgniter cannot know that you switched languages.

Comment: ok, so for now I have to choose one or another and stick to it. When deploying my site I will simply put the future URL then. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `LangSwitcher.php` as well in my CI and this is my working code:

your_controller.php

```
function __construct(){ 
        parent::__construct();      

        $lang = $this->session->userdata('site_lang');      
        $this->lang->load("message",$lang);
}
```

LanguageSwitch.php (controller)

```
<?php
class LangSwitch extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    function switchLanguage($language = "") {
        $language = ($language != "") ? $language : "english";
        $this->session->set_userdata('site_lang', $language);               
        $url = (null !== $this->session->userdata('ciutat_name')) ? $this->session->userdata('ciutat_name') : "tria_ciutat";  

        redirect(base_url($url));
    }
}
```

Then, you must have different folders for each lang inside language folder like: english , french with all files called: `message_lang.php`

with the translations this way:

```
$lang["text"]   = "Text in english";
```

In the view you use this every time you need to use a translation: `<?php echo lang('text'); ?>`

And to switch then lang you should go to: 
`<?php echo base_url('langswitch/switchLanguage/english'); ?>`

The structure is:

```
/controllers:
 - your_controllers.php //here in the __construct set the lang
 - langswitch.php //the langswitcher

/languages
  /english: message_lang.php  //here the translations
  /french: message_lang

/views
  your_views.php  //here you use lang()
```

Hope it helps to you or put some 'light' on your question.